# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when execute prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I tried to run `preparedStatement ps` to check whether the data is existed in database or not. Then it will run update if existed or insert if not existed. However, I receive syntax error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE date = '2019-05-22'' at line 1

I cannot spot where is the error. Anyone can help?

```
PreparedStatement ps,ps1;
        ps =con.prepareStatement("Select 1 from order WHERE date = ?");
        ps.setString(1, date);
        ResultSet rsOrder=ps.executeQuery();  
        if(rsOrder.next()) {  
            System.out.println("reOrder:  true");
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE order SET result = ?  WHERE date = ?");
            ps1.setString(1, json);
            ps1.setString(2, date);
            int rs=ps1.executeUpdate();

        }else {
            System.out.println("reOrder:  false");
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO order (date,result) VALUES (?,?)");
            ps1.setString(1, date);
            ps1.setString(2, json);
            int rs=ps1.executeUpdate();
        }
```

Comment: Chances are that `order` is a reserved keyword . You may have to escape it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`order`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-O) is the reserved word in MySQL. So it will not allow, with out escaping the reserved words.

You can escape it by adding ` around the keyword as:

```
Select 1 from `order` WHERE date = ?

UPDATE `order` SET result = ? WHERE date = ?

INSERT INTO `order` (date, result) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Comment: I just simply change the table name from order to orders but I accept your answer as well